# Unable to fetch public facebook feed through "HttpURLConnection"

Tags: android, facebook

Here is the code for what I'm trying to do. 
I have added the permission for internet access in the manifest file. Also, I do not want the user to login into facebook; just want the data to appear.

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL("https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=289781571139242");

                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = isw.read();
                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    data = isw.read();
                    System.out.print(current);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: does your app crashed?

Comment: @hardcoded no. The screen just remains blank, only showing title bar.